# Best strategy to maximize outcome in Binomial Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is the following:

> Given a multiple choice test with 12 "yes" or "no" questions, for which you need 8 correct answers to pass. You answer randomly, but know that 6 out of the twelve questions have answer "yes" (although you don't know which ones), what is the best strategy to maximize the likelyhood of passing?

My approach feels unnecessarily complicated and might be wrong, I feel like I am missing something obvious.

**Results:**

- I get $22.7\%$ chance of passing for $j = 10$.
- I get $27.27\%$ for $j=8$.
- I get $\approx 12\%$ for $j=7$.
- I get $\approx 28.35 \%$ for $j=6$

**My take went as follows:**

I want to find how many "yes" you should put at random in the test, in order to maximize the odds of getting $8$ answers correct.

Here is my approach:

The upper Line is the answer of the candidate ($1$ for yes, $0$ for no) and the lower Line is the solution to the test:
$$ \omega =  \begin{pmatrix} \omega_1 & \omega_2 & \cdots & \omega_6 & \omega_7 & \cdots &\omega_{12} \\ T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_6 & T_7 & \cdots & T_{12} \end{pmatrix}$$
Where $\omega_i$ is answer of a candidate to the $i$-th question and $T_i$ the Solution to said question. If $\omega_i = T_i$, then the answer is correct.

Given a test, we can rearrange the order of the questions such that $\omega$ is equivalent to some $$[\omega] =  \begin{pmatrix} \omega_{\pi(1)} & \omega_{\pi(2)} & \cdots & \omega_{\pi(3)} & \omega_{\pi(7)} & \cdots &\omega_{\pi(12)} \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ Where $\pi$ is some permutation of the columns.

Now, let $1 \leq j \leq 12$ be the number of "yes" answers, we have $\binom{12}{j}$ possible ways to answer the test.

- For $j=12$, we always get $6$ correct answers, but never $8$.
- For $j=11$, we can get a maximum of $7$ correct answers.
- For $j=10$, things get more interesting and my attempt is too long to write down, but I reason as follows: All elements are equivalent to one of the following possible scenarios:
  \begin{align*}
           r_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 &  \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
                                  1 & 1 & \cdots  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
         & r_2& = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
                                  1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
            r_3 &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
                                   1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix} & & 
       \end{align*}
  And by counting the number of possible permutations of each distinguishalbe column of each representant, we get the number of possibilities tied to each number of correct answer. Only $[r_1]$ can get us to pass and *we get a $22.7\%$ chance of passing for $j = 10$.*

I use a similar process for the rest.

Here is my concrete computation in the case $j=6$, where $S(r_i)$ is the number of correct answers associated to a certain respresentant and the numbers below for example $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ correspond to the number of columns of this form that any element equivalent to $r_i$ has:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat more generally, suppose there are $n$ questions, of which $m$ have correct answer Yes, and you need $r$ correct to pass.  You answer Yes to $k$ questions, and No to the others.  If you get $i$ correct Yes answers, then you must have had $m-i$  incorrect No answers, therefore $n-k - (m-i)$ correct No answers for a total of
$n-k-m+2i$ correct answers; the number of incorrect Yes answers was $k-i$.  The probability of this is
$$ P(n-k-m+2i) = \frac{{m \choose i}{n-m \choose k-i}}{{n \choose k}} $$
where of course we need $\max(0, m+k-n) \le i \le \min(m,k)$.
To pass you need $n-k-m+2i \ge r$, i.e. $i \ge (r+m+k-n)/2$.

Unfortunately I don't see a short-cut to avoid computing and adding the probabilities $P(n-k-m+2i)$ for $\max(0, m+k-n, (r+m+k-n)/2) \le i \le \min(m,k)$ for each $k$. Well, you don't have to compute all those binomial coefficients: note that

$$ P(n-k-m+2(i+1)) = \frac{(m-i)(k-i)}{(i+1)(n-m-k+i+1)} P(n-k-m+2i)$$
when $P(n-k-m+2i) > 0$.

I confirm your results in the case $n=12$, $m=6$, $r = 8$.